# The most common Google Play Services version

Tags: android

My app is supporting Android 4.0.3+. Setting Google Play Services too high forces the user to download it. Setting it too low may result in the API not performing up to expectations. The current version that I use is `6.5.87` but I know that it is too high. What is the appropriate version?

Comment: play services will continuously attempt to force the user to update to the latest version, I wouldn't bother with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the latest version and add a check if the version installed on the device is too low. If yes, provide some info window to force the user to download the latest one. I do that and I was neither confronted with complaints of users nor did any user have problems.
It's not your fault that people don't install updates.

See also: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29